# How can I get the full archive of information on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-archive

How can I get the full archive of information on Facebook . I tried " Download a copy of your Facebook data" and I received only part of the information .I am not receiving messages deleted. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

[Ask Ars](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/01/ask-ars-does-facebook-auto-delete-content-after-a-certain-period-of-time/)

Facebook:

> confirmed that as long as you have not deleted the content yourself—or in the case of a message between two people, both people have not deleted it—the content should stay online indefinitely.

Not all content is retained and hence recoverable.